# How to remember previously used settings in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using Matplotlib library in Python.
Assume in X-Axis, I have options from a to z.
Assume in Y-Axis, I have options from a to z.
Default is a vs a

Now I have plotted "k" vs "p"

When I open for the next time, is there a way that matplotlib remember the previously used settings, in this case "k" vs "p", rather than "a" vs "a"

Comment: Can you show some code as an example to be precise in what you mean? What do you mean by _options_?

Comment: I created a GUI using Tkinter, In that for x-axis, I have a dropdown from "a" to "z". Similarly for Y-axis, I have a dropdown from "a" to "z". For the first time, if I have selected plot between "k" vs "p", then for the next time, is there a way that matplotlib can remember "k" vs "p" in dropdown directly.